# vue app not working after npm run build for production

Tags: vue.js

[image]So I created a simple app with vue and works as I expected. But since I ran *npm run build* and I tried to run that project from /dist directory(for produnction) I just stops. What am i missing here guys?[image]

Comment: could you please show the errors in browser console?

Comment: It's not supposed to be workable without a webserver if it relies on it somehow, most commonly through a router

Comment: Its just a basic front end app. I mean it should run without live server right?

Comment: @DengSihan thanks . I uploaded the picture with the error(1st one)

Comment: @Sachin It seems like you programmed this web by something like `vue-cli`/`vite`, they will run a nodejs process so you can visit the page by something like `localhost:3000` during the development. After building the code for production, there is no nodejs anymore(client side render). And accroding to the picture, you open the html file by `file://` instead of `http(s)://`, so please check the js file paths in your `index.html`

Comment: @DengSihan spot on . Thanks man. My associated js files were  relative mode for server, but i they should be on absolute path to run without server

Comment: You probably need to do `npm run serve` to point the server to the dist dir. Then it will show you a ne `localhost` portnumber which is connected to the dist dir.